# Trouble casting Dictionary to Array

Tags: json, swift

My app crashes when I use this line of code.

```
self.cartProducts = responceDictionary!["result"] as! [AnyObject]
```

`responceDictionary` is JSON data that I need to be stored in an Array as `AnyObject`.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can't cast dictionary to array, the types are not related. If the object is supposed to be dictionary, why don't you cast it to dictionary? Is your question related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803668/parsing-json-returns-nil)?

Comment: Please add the format of your response. As @vadian says if it's a dictionary you can't cast it to an array.

Comment: @vadian I believe that `result` is array.

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev If the value for key `result` was array why does the code crash? @Minimoore: What error message do you get?

Comment: responceDictionary is a dictionary but value is Array probably.

Comment: @gyer Yes thats correct

Comment: @vadian crashes because of unwrapping nil probably

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev How do you know? It will crash also if `result` is not an array.

Comment: @vadian I don't know, I believe :)

Comment: @vadian Yes it was related to the post you've linked

Comment: @Minimoore26 Then the value for key `result` is clearly a dictionary (`[String:Any]`).

Comment: @vadian Could you show me how to implement this in an answer format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments the value for key `result` is most likely a dictionary.

While receiving data from a remote source avoid exclamation marks and unwrap the optionals safely:

```
if let responce = responceDictionary, let result = responce["result"] as? [String:Any] {
   print(result)
   // go on extracting data from result
]
```

Comment: How would I assign 'result' to cartProducts as there would be a clash between [String:Any] and AnyObject?

Comment: If `cartProducts` is an array you can't assign `result`. Read the JSON, you need to extract the desired array from the `result` dictionary

Comment: I don't understand? I need all the data from the `result` dictionary

Comment: Then you have to declare `cartProducts` to `[String:Any]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
guard let cartProducts = responceDictionary?["result"] as? [AnyObject] else { return }
self.cartProducts = cartProducts
```